# Can you prevent a human victim from becoming a zombie after he/she is attacked by a Chryssalid?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Can you prevent a human victim from becoming a zombie after he/she is attacked by a Chryssalid?  I was wondering if I should grenade my dead soldier after he was taken down by a Chryssalid.

Comment: Remember, if a poster correctly answers your question then you can mark their answer as accepted so that other users may benefit from it.

Answer (score 20):

Yes you may. If you cause explosive damage in the area that the body is located, it will not rise as a zombie (I've tried this on dead civilians, and would imagine it works the same for members of your squad).

Comment: I'd like to add that there is also nothing wrong with preventative explosives to blow up civilians/weak squad members (and surrounding aliens) to prevent chryssalidization.

Comment: I would never blow up squad mates, at least not ones who are still able to pull triggers- I'd let critically wounded ones bleed out (or at the very least, dismiss them when they heal up) but actively reduce my firepower?  Thats sheer madness